# force property implementation on derived classes

Tags: c#

I have `Person.cs` which will be implemented by, for example, the `Player` class. 
`Person` has an `ExperienceLevelType` property.

I want to force all classes that derived from `Person` to implement their own version of the `ExperienceLevelType` property.

```
public abstract Person
{
    public enum ExperienceLevel { Kid, Teenager}
    public virtual ExperienceLevel Experience {get; set;}
}

public abstract Player:Person
{
    public override ExperienceLevel Experience
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could declare it `abstract`?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

That's what [`abstract`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf985hc5.aspx) is for:

```
public abstract class Person
{
    public enum ExperienceLevel { Kid, Teenager}
    public abstract ExperienceLevel Experience { get; set; }
}
```

If you want to force derived classes to implement the property themselves while at the same time providing some reusable scaffolding to help them, expose the scaffolding as `protected` members inside `Person`.

Comment: great. How could you override Experience property in child class (Player)?

Comment: The same way as your virtual property.

Answer (score 0):

You could make `Person` an interface(and have it impliment nothing) OR you can make `Person` implement a custom interface `IPerson` which has your property

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to declare the method as abstract, it forces the sub-classes to implement it.