# How to force derived class to implement a property in C#

Tags: c#, abstract-class, abstract

I have scenario like below

```
public abstract class Test 
{
   public string name; 
   public abstract bool is_selected();
}

public class Campus : Test 
{  

}
```

Now Campus must and should implement is_selected() method otherwise it throws an error.
Adding to the same lines I want 'name' field also like that. I mean name field must be given a value.

How can I do that?
Any help greatly appreciated.

*Thanks in advance :)*

Comment: Make it abstract also

Comment: Does this answer your question? [force property implementation on derived classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13571693/force-property-implementation-on-derived-classes)

Comment: @Jonesopolis, there is no abstract field in C#

Comment: Thanks @shingo I was thinking too quickly and didn’t notice that. It would need to be a property, then should be made abstract

Comment: Familiarize with the concept of Properties. Then use an abstract Property instead of a Field. Having public fields in classes is usually bad design.

Answer (score 4):

I can find two options

1. Use a parameterized constructor, so the derived class must provide a constructor which initialize the fields.

```
public abstract class Test 
{
   public string name;
   protected Test(string name){ this.name = name; }
}

public class Campus : Test 
{
   public Campus() : base("Init the name here") {}
}
```

2. Use an abstract property, this is already metioned by other people.

```
public abstract class Test 
{
   public abstract string name { get; }
}

public class Campus : Test 
{  
   public override string name => "name";
}
```

Comment: And while he's at it, he should follow standard naming conventions for properties.